# How to handle rightly json data in go passed by curl through docker by curl

Tags: json, docker, go, struct

I have docker container. There are a server(on Go) that handler post requests on 8000 port. That code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
)

type tv_type struct { 
    brand string `json:"brand"`
    manufacturer string `json:"manufacturer"`
    model string `json:"model"`
    year int16 `json:"year"`
} 

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.Method == http.MethodGet {
           //blahblah
        }
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello WORLD")
       if r.Method == http.MethodPost {
        connStr := "user=www password=qwerty dbname=products sslmode=disable"
        db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
        defer db.Close()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        } 
        decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
        var t tv_type
        err = decoder.Decode(&t)

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        _, err = db.Exec("insert into TV (brand, manufacturer, model, year) values ($1, $2, $3, $4)",
            t.brand, t.manufacturer, t.model, t.year)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        } else {
                        fmt.Println(t.brand, t.manufacturer, t.model, t.year)
            fmt.Fprintln(w, "Inserting has been succesfully")
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

Docker container was runned that requests on 80 own port proxy on 8000 port of docker container.

And after run this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"brand":"samsung", "manufacturer":"samsung", "model":"x1", "year":2015 }' http://localhost:80
Hello WORLD
Inserting has been succesfully
```

But data that is getted was wrong(nil,nil,nil,0):

```
go run /home/go/hello.go 
   0
```

Comment: First check for data inside `tv_type` struct is coming properly by printing the struct. Then Check if the data that you have inserted got inserted successfully into the database.

Comment: I have inserted ("", "","", 0).

Comment: <code> type tv_type struct { 
    brand string `json:"brand"`
    manufacturer string `json:"manufacturer"`
    model string `json:"model"`
    year int16 `json:"year"`
} <code>

Comment: Ok so you have inserted empty strings and zero value into the database. Is that you really want to insert then what is your question. No not th struct check your edited question where I am printing the data after decoding the json coming from  the server.

Comment: I want to insert {"brand":"samsung", "manufacturer":"samsung", "model":"x1", "year":2015 } that i send by curl

Comment: Add your full code including the struct in your question. May be there is something wrong when unmarshaling data.

Comment: You mention Docker a couple of times; are there any differences running your program under Docker vs. not?

Comment: A [mcve] would help understand this.  It needs to include the struct definition (in the question itself), the output of the `fmt.Println` call that dumps the decoded structure at insert time, and the retrieval code that's printing the unexpected answer.

Comment: I wrote this code rightly in a docker container

Comment: You have to export the struct fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major issue with your code is when you are trying to decode the json provided by the server in the response is your struct is unable to unmarshal the data. Since struct fields are unexported. Change the struct fields to uppercase as:

```
type Tv_type struct { 
    Brand string `json:"brand"`
    Manufacturer string `json:"manufacturer"`
    Model string `json:"model"`
    Year int16 `json:"year"`
}
```

Check [Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/I-hpWPegOaM) for working code.

It is also mentioned in Golang spec for [Unmarshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) as:

> To unmarshal JSON into a struct, Unmarshal matches incoming object
>   keys to the keys used by Marshal (either the struct field name or its
>   tag), preferring an exact match but also accepting a case-insensitive
>   match. By default, object keys which don't have a corresponding struct
>   field are ignored (see Decoder.DisallowUnknownFields for an
>   alternative).